# i keep getting indexerror:index list out of range on python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, indexing

```
if productid==row[0]: #This means it runs every row in the reader file which is the csv file in this case
    price = row[2]
    stocklevel = row[3]
    reorderlevel = row[4]
    targetlevel = row[5]
    total = float(amount)*float(price)
    totalprice = float(totalprice)+float(total)
    stocklevel = float(stocklevel)-float(amount)
    newstock = (stocklevel)
    b = open('products.csv', 'w')
    a = csv.writer(b)
    data = [['row[3]', 'row[4]', 'row[5]'],
           ['293', '219'],
           ['54', '13']]
    a.writerows(data)
    b.close()
```

Basically I keep getting this error File

> "E:\Python Programme\pythonv5.py", line 71, in 
>       productlist()   File "E:\Python Programme\pythonv5.py", line 9, in productlist
>       print(row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[2]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you show the data structure of your CSV file and it's contents? Because an index error is pretty obvious. In this case row[0] (or 1 or 2) doesn't exist.

Comment: The error is refering to a line with a print statement, yet your code shows no print statement. index list out of range means you are trying to access say, the third object on a list that only has 2 objects. Or your list could empty and then it would say that anytime. Try changing `print(row[0]...` to `print(len(row).)` to see how many objects are in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if len(row) > 0 and productid==row[0]:
   #rest of the code here ...
```

You need to make sure row list has a length to be indexed.

Comment: The way the answer is formulated now, it barely qualifies as an answer and it's more of a comment. I think some explanation as to why this solves the problem would be in place here